# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './{File_name}.py'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I am making an IDE on python as a fun project but I have problem listing the file directories like in vs code (File tree). it gives me `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './file.py'` as far as I understand it happens because it searches file in the directory where **Main file is located** but I don't know how to fix it here's the code

```
########################################
#TREE
########################################
file_tree = Frame(root)
file_tree.pack(side='left', fill=Y, expand=NO)
def open_dir():
    for i in tree.get_children():
        tree.delete(i)
    path = askdirectory()
    abspath = os.path.abspath(path)
    root_node = tree.insert('', 'end', text=abspath, open=True)
    process_directory(root_node,abspath)

def process_directory( parent, path):

        for p in os.listdir(path):
            abspath = os.path.join(path, p)
            isdir = os.path.isdir(abspath)
            oid = tree.insert(parent, 'end', text=p, open=False)
            if isdir:
                process_directory(oid, abspath)

def Open_file_from_list_box(value):
    global file
    item_id = tree.selection()
    file = tree.item(item_id, 'text') # get the filename from 'text' option
    filepath = os.path.join(value,file)     
    editArea.delete(1.0,END)
    with open(filepath,"r") as f:
        editArea.insert(1.0,f.read())

tree = ttk.Treeview(file_tree)
tree.pack(expand=YES,fill=BOTH)
path = '.'
tree.heading('#0', text=path, anchor='w')
abspath = os.path.abspath(path)
root_node = tree.insert('', 'end', text=abspath, open=True)
process_directory(root_node, abspath)

tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>",lambda event=None:Open_file_from_list_box(path))
```

I use Tkinter for the Gui.

Actually this code is from stack overflow but I don't remember from where I just modified it for my needs.

Comment: Relative path is relative to current working directory, not the directory where the file is located. Of course they may be one and the same

Comment: Your example isn't runnable. Please provide a runnable example. See [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to store the fullpath of the files using the item ID as the key:

```py
filepaths = {}

def process_directory(parent, path):
    for p in os.listdir(path):
        abspath = os.path.join(path, p)
        isdir = os.path.isdir(abspath)
        oid = tree.insert(parent, 'end', text=p, open=False)
        filepaths[oid] = abspath  # save the full pathname
        if isdir:
            process_directory(oid, abspath)

def Open_file_from_list_box(value):
    global file
    try:
        item_id = tree.selection()[0]
        filepath = filepaths[item_id] # get the full pathname
        editArea.delete(1.0,END)
        with open(filepath,"r") as f:
            editArea.insert(1.0,f.read())
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex.__class__.__name__, ex)
```

Comment: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple. Can I save it as str? because I need str in save_as function

Comment: Your posted code does not have a *save_as* function.  You should raise another question on that issue.  My answer addresses only the file not found issue.